# How to know whether my activity was resumed after an incoming call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

At first, it sound like a simple thing to do but I found it no so simple.
What I'm trying to achieve is to have my android app return to a certain state after an it went to the background upon an incoming call.

The question is, what is the best way to know whether my app went to foreground after the user rejected or ended an incoming call (that occurred while my app was in the foreground)?

I know I can use broadcast receivers to identify incoming calls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Once you app is resumed/restarted onResume/onRestart would be called, you do not need to listen for broadcast unless you are doing something with audio that will hamper the ongoing call.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can trust Android to reactivate your activity from background and call onResume() method.  When your activity is  about  to be put to background, onPause() will be called ( and this is only reliable callback )

Comment: I know I can trust the activity life cycle to work, however, there is no guarantee that the activity will not be destroyed after it went to the background. I would like to avoid storing data in shared preferences or on the SD.

Comment: onPause() is only callback guaranted to be called,  and android can destroy zour background activity at any time witout prir notice -  so if you like your data to be saved, do it in onPause()